# how to use kCICategoryDistortionEffect and kCICategoryGeometryAdjustment in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-image

I wants to add "Face-wrap" effect in my iOS app. After lots of searching i came to know that there is CoreImage Framework in iOS which provides some constants as kCICategoryDistortionEffect and kCICategoryGeometryAdjustment. I hope that both will help me in achieving my aim. But, now i am enable to find any example of how to use them. Can you please help me?
Thanks, in advance.